# What's the most efficient way to put all the stones in one pile?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

There are $k$ piles of $n_i$ stones, on every move you can choose two piles with sizes $a$ and $b$ and if $a \ge b$ take from the first pile $b$ stones and put to the second one, on other hand if $a < b$ - take $a$ from the second and put them to the first. What is the necessary and sufficient condition to put all stones in one pile and what is the smallest number of such operations to do it?

The first question is rather simple: iff $\frac{\sum{n_i}}{\gcd(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)}=2^p$
But I dont know answer for the second one, I can prove that it is $O(kp)$, but I think that we can do it much more quicker and my hypothesis is $O(k + p))$. Can anyone to prove it or may be refuse it?

May be there exists some better estimation for the number of moves, if you have, please tell me.

Comment: Plase, make titles informative. I have changed it, but maybe you can think of something more concise.

Comment: In case it helps: the time-reversed procedure is somewhat simpler to describe: start from a single pile, each movement selects a non-empty pile of even size, takes half of its stones and place them over any other pile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the following.

Fix $p$ and $k$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\gcd(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)=1$.

At first we calculate the number $P(p,k)$ of different possible initial positions $(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)$. It is well known and easy to show that the number $S(K,k)$ of different sequences $(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)$ of nonnegative integers (not necessarily satisfying the condition $\gcd(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)=1$) with $\sum n_i=K$ is equal to ${K+k-1}\choose{k-1}$. Fortunately, in our case $K=2^p$ is a power of a prime number $2$. Therefore we have that $\gcd(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)\not=1$ iff all $n_i$ are even. Thus the number $P(p,k)$ of different sequences 
$(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)$  satisfying the condition $\gcd(n_1, n_2 ... n_k)=1$ with 
$\sum n_i=K$ is equal to $S(K,k)–S(K/2,k)$.

Now we have the tree of positions with initial $P(p,k)$ vertices and $k$ roots and on each move we are going down to the root. It is easy to check that if a position $B$ was obtained from a position $A$ by moving stones from $i$-th pile to $j$-th, then the position $A$ is uniquely determined by $B$, $i$ and $j$. Therefore each vertex of the tree has no more than $k(k-1)$ vertices above it. Thus if we can reach a root of the tree from each of its vertices after going down at most $m$ moves, we should have the inequality $k[k(k-1)]^{m-1}\ge P=(p,k)$. In particular, for large $k$ and $2^p>>k$ it should give an asymptotic lower bound on $m$ of order $\frac{pk}{\operatorname{log}_2 k}-k$.

Comment: That is a necessary, but not sufficient condition.

Comment: This is a lower bound, which should be not $O(k+p)$.

Comment: I dont understand how you've counted number of positions. E.g. you have piles {2,1,1} and make {2, 2, 0}. Your assumption doesnt work, because gcd is two. AFAIU you've not counted this state or p became less by one.

Comment: :-) For my lower bound I have no need to count the number of *all* vertices of the tree. I need only to estimate the number of *initial* vertices from below (and I counted this number precisely) and to show that *each*  vertex of the tree can has no more than $k(k−1)$  vertices above it.

Comment: It seems that I understand idea but not details, may be you know worst case example?

Comment: @SavinovEvgeny No. But there is a standard way to such results. At first, we consider cases for small $p$ and $k$. Fix numbers $p$ and $k$ and consider the tree $T$ of *all* positions (it has $S(2^p,k)$ positions, but, for the sake of simplicity, it suffice to consider positions with $n_1\ge n_2\ge\dots n_k$).

Comment: Now we rank the positions. Initially, set rank $0$ to a root of the tree. Then recursively set rank $rank(v)$ of a vertex $v$ as follows $rank(v)=1+\{\min rank(u):u\in T, u$ is obtainable from $v\}$. A computer program is usually used for such tasks. Often such calculations yield an inductive base allowing to formulate a conjecture (or a bound) for general case. Then it rests to prove the conjecture. :-)

Comment: I think you formulated a good problem. I tried to google it, but, even somewhat surprisingly, 
I found nothing about it. In such the case we can can try to obtain some related results, write them down into a small article and publish it,  for instance in “[The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](http://www.combinatorics.org/)”. But I still suspect that the problem is known. Maybe we should google it more or ask a specialist about it (but I do not know whom).

Comment: I wrote program and could check only small values, and didn't get anyhing useful from it, because too many states required for solving and it takes exponential time.

Comment: It sounds worse than I expected. Can you provide the results for these small values which your program already checked?